# Transformação inversa no R para var continua cujo valor máx = Inf

Tags: banco-de-dados, r, data, transform

Tenho a seguinte `var` contínua:

```
> summary(banco1$rac)
Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max.     NA's 
0.000    5.077    6.694   17.380    8.728    4917.000  465
```

Esta `var` não apresenta distribuição normal e por isso apliquei uma transformação inversa:

```
inv.rac=1/banco1$rac
> summary(inv.rac)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
 0.0002  0.1146  0.1494     Inf  0.1970     Inf     465
```

A inversa apresenta valor `Max. = Inf`. Acredito que por esse motivo, o plot do qqnorm para esta variável transformada não esteja rodando. Apresenta a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
> qqnorm(inv.rac, main="Q-Q Plot Inversa da rac", xlab="Quantis Teóricos", ylab= "Quantis Observados")
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
```

Alguém sabe como poderia resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 1):

Pode tentar somar um valor muito pequeno aos valores iguais a zero. Por exemplo

```
inx <- which(banco1$rac == 0)
banco1$rac[inx] <- banco1$rac[inx] + .Machine$double.eps
```

Note que o inverso de `.Machine$double.eps` não dá `Inf`.

```
1/.Machine$double.eps
[1] 4.5036e+15
```

Se isto não resultar, tente `sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)`.

```
1/sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)
[1] 67108864
```

Veja a página de ajuda `?.Machine`.